Validate that form field input is Title Case formatted
I am trying to make an input with regex for the following pattern:

Force start first character with a capital letter
Force first character of other WORDS (letters) capital letter
Force all other letters in words lowercase
Allow numbers & special characters anywhere except 1st character of words



<input type="text" name="display_name" placeholder="Display Name" id="display_name" required minlength="1" maxlength="32" 
pattern="[A-Z].{1,1}[a-z1-9\W_]).{,}[ ]{,}[A-Z].{1,1}[a-z1-9\W_]).{,}[ ]{,}[A-Z].{1,1}[a-z1-9\W_]).{,}[ ]{,}">



Also, if you can do this pattern, can I also get the same pattern to use for php pregreplace.

Why does it make sense to validate client-side and sanitize on the server-side?

As pointed out in the comments, the older regex has some problems. So, you can try this new regex.
/^[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W_]+)(?:\s+[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W_]+(?=[A-Z]|\s|$))*)$/

This is a fiddle showing some test cases.
And here is the PHP in which this regex can be used.
$input = "YourInputStringHere";

$pattern = '/^[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W_]+)(?:\s+[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W_]+(?=[A-Z]|\s|$))*)$/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $input)) {
    echo "Valid input!";
} else {
    echo "Invalid input!";
}

And if you want to convert this into function, then try following:
function isValidName($name) {
    if ($name !== null && $name !== '') {
        $pattern = '/^[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W_]+)(?:\s+[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W_]+(?=[A-Z]|\s|$))*)$/';
        return preg_match($pattern, $name);
    }
    return false;
}

And, if you want to use Javascript to force the input to follow the regex, you can try the following:
document.getElementById('display_name').addEventListener('input', function() {
    // This will convert all letters to lowercase except the first letter of word.
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, function (char) {
        return char.toUpperCase();
    });
});

And the error_message is just a span. Also, after this Javascript, I don't think you would need the pattern thing in your input. So, if you are using this Javascript, you can remove the pattern from your input.
Hope this helps.

Thanks, but after testing, I notice it does not accept "Real Name".

@Antarctica-UFO But for me, its working for many inputs. See this fiddle

Invalid name: true I want to force the first letter of each word a capital if possible

the question is clear and correct. the answer provided almost works. it is very close, it should force the first letter of each word to be a capital if it is a letter. (but not to force the first character of other words to be a letter).

@Antarctica-UFO Now, I have updated the regex, and created a new fiddle for testing. (Don't know about the downvotes....)

Thanks Vansch!! I really appreciate that! This is the html regex pattern. I still need php for this same pattern and how could I use javascript to force the input to follow this pattern? I can hire someone to help me with just a few things like this. me@antarctica-ufo.com (so u know, I upvoted you, not downvoted!)

Thanks again Vansch but Javascript is not forcing the rest of letters in words to be lowercase

Ok, so you want like even if I enter two letters consecutive in uppercase, then it should directly convert second character to lowercase, am I right? I have updated my answer accordingly.

that is exactly correct, exactly what I want. But it still isn't working here for me. I will check back late tonight.

This answer is less refined than @thefourthbird's answer.

A few notes about the regex that you tried, which might not have the intended result:

This part .{1,1} is the same as writing just .
This part [a-z1-9\W_] will not match the number zero due to the range 1-9 and the \W could also match a newline
This part .{,} matches any character due to the dot, followed by matching {,} literally

When using PHP, you could use:
^[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*(?:\h+[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*)*$

The regex in parts matches:

^ Start of string
[A-Z] Match an uppercase char A-Z
[^A-Z\s]* Match 0+ times any character except an uppercase char A-Z or a whitespace char
(?: Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

\h+ Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
[A-Z][^A-Z\s]* Match a char A-Z and 0+ times any character except an uppercase char A-Z or a whitespace char


)* Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
$ End of string

See a regex demo and a PHP demo
For Javascript you could slightly change the regex to:
^[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*)*$

See another regex demo


const strings = [
  "A", "Ab", "Abc Def", "Ab A", "Test", "This", "This Is", "This Is A", "T_his I234s A#$%", "Real Name", "test", "TesT", "TeSt", "This is ", "This Is a"
];

const regex = /^[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*(?:\s+[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*)*$/m;

strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(`${s} => ${regex.test(s) ? "Match" : "No Match"}`);
});



